# Dynamically injecting component vs controlling it via *ngIf

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if, angular-dynamic-components

I have a scenario where I have a component which does some `http` requests to show data and if there is an exception while doing so, I want to show instead just the error component.

Does it make sense to have the error component already on the template as

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="showError">
    <error-view></error-view>
</ng-template>
```

and set the flag to true to show.

Or inject the component dynamically using `ComponentFactoryResolver` once there is error?

Comment: ComponentFactoryResolver would be an overkill for most of the cases. Using conditional rendering with ngIf is fair and better intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

The `*ngIf` directive doesn't immediately render the elements.

The following

```html
<ng-template [ngIf]="showError">
  <error-view></error-view>
</ng-template>
```

or the shorter variant

```html
<error-view *ngIf="showError"></error-view>
```

doesn't actually render the component until the `showError` is true.

During the rendering, the `ng-template` would be replaced with a diagnostic comment like

```html
<!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
```

So I'd say using `ComponentFactoryResolver` is unnecessary in this situation.